# Break interval between two on a particular date

Tags: php

start date = 2015-01-01 
end date = 2015-02-01

date = 2015-01-15

I want two intervals like this

interval 1 
start date = 2015-01-01
end date = 2015-01-15

interval 2 
start date = 2015-01-16
end date = 2015-02-01

my code seems like this

```
<?php 

$fromdate = '2015-12-01';
$todate   ='2015-01-01';

if ($fromdate < '2015-12-18' && $todate > '2015-12-18')
{
 // here i have to split interval into two intervals and get data from both tables old_orders and new_orders
    $fromdate1 = '2015-12-01'; $todate1 = '2015-12-15';
    $fromdate2 = '2015-12-16'; $todate2 = '2015-01-01';



$query1 = "SELECT * FROM new_orders WHERE date BETWEEN '".$fromdate1."' AND '".$todate1."'";
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM new_orders WHERE date BETWEEN '".$fromdate2."' AND '".$todate2."'";

}
else if ($fromdate > '2015-12-18')
{
    $query1 = "SELECT * FROM new_orders WHERE date BETWEEN '".$fromdate."' AND '".$todate."'";
}
else if ($todate < '2015-12-18')
{
    $query1 = "SELECT * FROM old_orders WHERE date BETWEEN '".$fromdate."'" AND '".$todate."'";
}
```

Comment: Any code that you can show us? It seems fairly straight forward.

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php

$startDate = '2015-01-01';
$endDate = '2015-02-01';
$date = '2015-01-15';

$intervals = array();

$intervals[] = array('startDate'=>$startDate, 'endDate'=>$date);
$intervals[] = array('startDate'=>date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date . ' +1 day')), 'endDate'=>$endDate);
```

In `$intervals` array you have structure like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [startDate] => 2015-01-01
            [endDate] => 2015-01-15
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [startDate] => 2015-01-16
            [endDate] => 2015-02-01
        )
)
```

Comment: thanks  exactly this i want and also thanks to all of you guyz

Answer (score 0):

If I did understand you, you'll need something like that:

```
function isDateBetweenDates ($date, $startDate, $endDate) {
     $strDate = strtotime($date);
     $strStartDate = strtotime($startDate);
     $strEndDate = strtotime($endDate);

     return ($strDate >= $strStartDate && $strDate <= $strEndDate);
}

$date = "2015-01-15";
$startDate = "2015-01-01";
$endDate = "2015-02-01";

class Interval {}
$interval = new Interval();

if (isDateBetweenDates($date, $startDate, $endDate)) {
        $interval->firstPart = array(
            "start" => $startDate,
            "end" => $date
        );

        $newDate = new DateTime($date);
        $newDate->modify("1 day");

        $interval->secondPart = array(
            "start" => $newDate->format("Y-m-d"),
            "end" => $endDate
        );
}
```

Best regards.